# Import & Export ES6 keywords in Jest & Mozilla extension development

Tags: node.js, firefox, import, jestjs, export

I'm edveloping a **Mozilla Firefox** extension using ***Node.js*** and I'm trying to cover my implementation with unit tests using ***Jest***.
So my *package.json* looks like so:

```json
{
  "name": "keep-your-session",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Mozilla Firefox extension plugin to store and manage browsing sessions",
  "main": "manifest.json",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-node",
    "transform": {}
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/BartoszKlonowski/keep-your-session.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=13.0.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Firefox",
    "Extension",
    "Plugin",
    "Session"
  ],
  "author": "Bartosz Klonowski",
  "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/BartoszKlonowski/keep-your-session/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/BartoszKlonowski/keep-your-session#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "web-ext": "^6.1.0"
  }
}
```

To test some of logic functions I used `export` syntax to export functions in it and import them in the test implementation file.

Two problems appeared:

**1.** Jest does not recognize `import`, `export` keywords throwing an error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/content.tests.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
...
    Details:

    P:\Projekty\KeepYourSession\__tests__\content.tests.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { eventTargetIDToCommand } from '../src/popup/MainPopup';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

**2.** Extension stopped working - it works when there's no `export` in the file, so obviously it fails to launch the extension due to lack of transpiled/packed sources.

---

I've searched a lot for this problem and tried to add different plugins of Babel, or configure it in various ways, but obviously there's something missing and I just don't know what.

**So my question is:**
How to correctly configure my environment to transpile all the sources correctly for Mozilla Firefox extension and for Jest testing?